# supporting multiple screens issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm a little confused after reading [Designing for Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html) in the Android documentation. There is a tool in Eclipse to preview the layout in different screens. And I can see from there that certain images are out of place and too big or too small. For example in this screenshot the big one is how it should look like and all the others are what it would look like in other screens. As you can see the jar with brain is out of place in all screens screens(except for Galaxy Nexus). [image]

Throughout my application I've used all the best practices:

1. I have multiple versions of all the images located in drawable-xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi and ldpi, xxhdpi
2. I've used wrap-content and fill-parent wherever possible
3. I've used RelativeLayout
4. I've used dp for margins and paddings

layout xml for this particular layout in the screenshot:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/wall_nobrainjar"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/brainjar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="129dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="215dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/red_paint"
        android:background="@drawable/brainjar"
        android:onClick="zoomImage" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/riddle_book"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/red_paint"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="83dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="zoomImage" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/zoomed_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/brainjar_zoomed"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/brainjar_zoomed_image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/brain_grey"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/riddleBook_zoomed_image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/riddle_zoomed"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/red_paint"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/brainjar"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="zoomImage" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What is my problem? the only thing I haven't followed is having multiple versions of layouts (-large, -small,etc). Is that the problem? If it is there a way to solve it without having many layout files. Currently I have only one layout folder, where I've put all my layout files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create different folders of name **layout-small**,
  **layout-large**,
  **layout-xlarge**
  in **res**  folder
- Copy-paste all ur .xml's from ur layout to thes folder
- Open all the xml's & set the margins with using different screen sizes one by one
- Then u can run & see the app in different size emulators

*It is the simplest way !*

Comment: Thank you VivekWarde. I'll try that and will come back if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** Don't be lazy.

**More detailed answer:** Your background is scaled to fit the screen, but your other images are are not, so the ratio between the background and other images are different on different devices, if you look carefully you will see that the brain jar is not only in different places, but with different sizes. To solve this, you simply, or not that simply ;) need to add layouts for different screen sizes, to layout and scale your brain jar probably.

Comment: Thank you Babibu for your detailed answer. That's what I don't get, why the images are too big or small. For what then I have drawable-hdpi, xhdpi and mdpi? Aren't those different versions of images supposed to solve this exact issue?
The second question is, why is it dp doesn't solve the problem of positioning. Isn't dp abstract measure for a reason and android should automatically calculate for each device the correct placement based on this dp?
P.S. I'm not being lazy. It's just I have to finish this in 3 days. Not enough time

Comment: @Nazerke No, hdpi, xhdpi suppose to keep the image true size, like what you would measure if you use a real life ruler on different devices. This is also the difference between dp and p. But if you make your background fit screen, then all those doesn't matter as you scaling the image only by the screen size.